# C, Create Processes and wait

Tags: c, winapi

Hi I'm creating more than one process with the CreateProcess
and I need to wait all of them to finish, to analyze the results.

And I cant WaitForSingleObject because I need all of the processes running at the same time.

Since each process has a handle at [Process_Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (hProcess)
I tought it was ok to use [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28v=VS.85%29.aspx),but the parent process ends without waiting for the child.
Is it ok to use WaitForMultipleObjects or there is a better way?

This is how I'm creating the processes:

```
#define MAX_PROCESS 3

STARTUPINFO si[MAX_PROCESS];
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi[MAX_PROCESS];
WIN32_FIND_DATA fileData;
HANDLE find;

int j=0, t=0;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));


for (t = 0; t < MAX_PROCESS; t++)
    si[t].cb = sizeof(si[0]);

ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));    

while (FindNextFile(find, &fileData) != 0) 
{
    // Start the child process. 
    if (!CreateProcess(_T("C:\\Users\\Kumppler\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\  \teste3\\Debug\\teste3.exe"),   // No module name (use command line)
                       aux2,           // Command line
                       NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
                       NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
                       TRUE,           // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                       0,              // No creation flags
                       NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
                       NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
                       &si[j],         // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                       &pi[j])         // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
       ) 
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }
    j++;

    //find next file related

}       
FindClose(find);        

WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_PROCESS, &pi[j].hProcess, FALSE, INFINITE);
//wait and analyze results
```

Btw I'm trying not to use threads.

Answer (score 3):

WaitForMultipleObjects expects array of handles:

```
HANDLE hanldes[MAX_PROCESS];
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PROCESS; ++i)
{
  handles[i] = pi[i].hProcess;
}

WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_PROCESS, handles, TRUE, INFINITE);
```

Also you should know that maximum array size of handles for WaitForMultipleObjects is limited to MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS (which is 64).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wait for all the HANDLEs set 'bWaitAll' (the third parameter) to 'TRUE'.